# Does the 3rd benefit of the Sentinel feat combine with reach weapons?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, reach

The third benefit of the [Sentinel](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/feats/sentinel) feat (PHB, p. 169-170) says:

> When a creature within 5 feet of you makes an attack against a target other than you, you can use your reaction to make a melee weapon attack against the attacking creature.

The "reach" property of weapons applies to normal attacks, bonus attacks, and opportunity attacks, but this Sentinel attack is not explicitly any of those.  Can I make this attack with my reaction against someone 10 feet away who makes an attack against a target other than me if I have a weapon with a 10-foot reach?

Comment: @NautArch: Though the wording in the errata is different, that change seems to have been made in [the very first errata in 2015](http://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/Errata_PH.pdf), and only applies to the 2nd benefit, not the 3rd. (For reference, bullet point 2 originally said: "Creatures within 5 feet of you provoke opportunity attacks from you even if they take the Disengage action before leaving your reach.")

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This has been [addressed by Jeremy Crawford](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2015/11/12/sentinel-reach-benefit/), and the answer is, indeed, **no**:

> The final benefit of the Sentinel feat is unaffected by a weapon's range. The benefit is limited to 5 feet.

Comment: Though the wording in the errata is different, that change seems to have been made in [the very first errata in 2015](http://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/Errata_PH.pdf), and only applies to the 2nd benefit, not the 3rd. (For reference, bullet point 2 originally said: "Creatures within 5 feet of you provoke opportunity attacks from you even if they take the Disengage action before leaving your reach.") Sorry for the repetition!

Answer (score 23):

## No, it doesn't

The feat explicitly says "within 5 feet", rather than "in your reach" or "in melee".